# Why might a joined thread be missing from deadlock detection in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, deadlock

I am trying to debug a deadlock in some Ruby code bit something doesn't seem to add up. I'm not a Ruby developer so maybe I'm making an invalid assumption somewhere. I want to understand a bit more about how Ruby performs its deadlock detection.

Here is an example of what I am seeing:

- There are 9 threads. The first is the main and current thread. The other 8 are worker threads.
- The first worker thread goes off and does its thing and eventually gets to a `::IO:readlines`.
- The next 4 go and start something but then `wait` on a `ConditionVariable` which the first worker thread will eventually `signal`.
- The other 3 have nothing to do and stop.
- Now the main thread calls `join` on all the worker threads after starting them, joining on the 1st worker first.
- This `join` fails saying:

  > No live threads left. Deadlock? (fatal)
- It then prints out 5 threads, 1 is the main thread and the other 4 are the 4 workers that are waiting. The 1st worker thread is missing.
- The 1st worker is still alive, it carries on doing its thing after the error.

What are the possible reasons why a thread that is being joined on is not included in the deadlock detection? Or is this simply not possible and my understanding of what is really going incorrect?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". When asking us to help debug code we need to see the code. Descriptions are important, but, like a picture, the code is worth 1,000 words.

Comment: I disagree with you lot here. I am not asking you to debug the code. I just want a better understanding of how Ruby does its deadlock detection in the general sense and what the possible reasons may be rather than the exact reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding was not correct. Even though it appeared from the debug logging that it was joining on the first thread it was not. It had joined on the first thread and it was the second one that caused the deadlock.

Once I identified that it was much simpler to track down why the first thread was completing but not signalling the remaining threads.

This may have been caused by `puts` buffering. So either `flush` the output, set it to `sync` or unroll the loop so that the joins appear on different lines and the backtrace tells you the correct one.

In short, trust the output from the deadlock. If it conflicts with your assumptions then validate your assumptions.